# How do I resolve a missing file error that arises when I run my program through the src file?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

I am new to programming and am completing a project in Eclipse for Java and I am running into an error I can't resolve. When I run the program through the src folder, I get the following error:`

```
 Missing file Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "GraphNode.getId()" because "homeNode" is null at Main.main(Main.java:19)`
```

However, when I don't run my program through the src folder and instead run it straight through the default package, my program works completely fine. Does anyone have any idea what may be causing this issue? I tried deleting and redownloading Eclipse in addition to manually re-adding the classes into the src folder multiple times, and it doesn't work. If necessary I can provide my code, but since the program runs in the default package completely fine I don't think the error is in the code.

As I mentioned, I tried deleting and redownloading Eclipse in addition to manually re-adding the classes into the src folder multiple times. The outcome I expected was for the program to run the same through the src folder as it does through the default package, but what actually resulted was the error:

```
Missing file Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "GraphNode.getId()"
because "homeNode" is null at Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

Comment: Error messages and logs should use code format, not quoted format.

Comment: *When I run the program through the src folder* What does that mean? Are you running it at the command line or something?

Comment: No, sorry for the confusion. What I meant when the classes are in the src folder and I run the main class, I receive an error. When the classes are not in a src folder and are simply in the default package and I run the main class, I don't receive an error.
Maybe these screenshots will clarify:

https://pasteboard.co/l43pwIrRFFzk.png

https://pasteboard.co/QGJXA0XujEb6.png

Comment: In your first screenshot you use Java 17 (and the project folder is used as source folder which is not recommended, but maybe unrelated here). In contrast, in your second screenshot you use Java 8 (Java 8 is less restrictive than Java 17, which may result in different behavior in rare cases). Please show your code. `"homeNode" is null` in line 19. Where and how is `homeNode` set?